# How to repeat a for loop in C language

Tags: c++, c

I am a C language beginner. I got this assignment to program for diving score. the rule is that the score has to be between 0 to 10, if the score is invalid, the program should ask for a new score, and there should be at least 4 judges to give the score. 
I am having problem with the part with the for loop, I want the program to keep checking if the score is invalid or not, but I couldn't repeat the for loop. please help me, here is my code.

```
    for (index = 0; index < judges; index++)
    {
        printf ("Enter the score for judges #%d(1-10): ", index + 1);
        scanf ("%f", &score[index]);

        if ((score[index] >= 0) && (score[index] <= 10))
        {
            totalscore += score[index];
        }
        else
        {
            totalscore = 0;

            for (index = 0; index < judges; index++)
            {
                printf ("11111Enter the score for Judges #%d(0-10): ", index + 1);
                scanf ("%f", &score[index]);

                if ((score[index] >= 0) && (score[index] <= 10))
                {
                    totalscore += score[index];

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    

}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, as a courtesy to your readers and as a favour to yourself.

Comment: Sorry about this, I will just leave the part that I have problem with.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
do
{
    prompt();
    scanf(&variable);
}
while (is_invalid (variable));
```

This way, you only need to check if the variable is valid in one place and you only need to prompt in one place.

Your multiple `while`s and `if`s are error prone and hard to get right.

So instead of:

```
printf ("Enter the number of judges (must bewteen 4-8): ");
scanf ("%d", &judges);
if ((judges < 4) || (judges > 8)){
    while (true) {
    printf ("\ninvaild number of judges\n\nEnter the number of judges (must between 4-8): ");
    scanf ("%d", &judges);
    if ((judges >= 4) && (judges <= 8)) {
        break;
    }}}
```

Use:

```
do
{
    printf ("\n\nEnter the number of judges (must between 4-8): ");
    scanf ("%d", &judges);
}
while ((judges < 4) || (judges > 8));
```

Comment: Would you not rather use `do {var=read_var();} while(is_invalid(var));`?

Comment: Suggest encouraging the OP to check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

why you use the same variable "index" in the inner for loop? it'll mess up everything. suppose you have 4 judges, you have inputed 3 and 5. you try to input 17,  and now the index is 2, right? but the score is invald, so it will goto the "else { xxxxx }" , here you have a inner for loop "for (index = 0; index < judges; index++)" , so the variable "index" come back to 0! IMO in this case, "while" is better:

```
while ((score[index] < 0) || (score[index] > 10))
    printf(xxxxxxx)
    scanf(xxxxxxx)
```

if you really need more than one for loop, you should use different variables:

```
for (i=0; i<judges; i++)
    /*DO STH*/

for (j=0; j<judges; j++)
    /*DO STH*/

for (k=0; k<judges; k++)
    /*DO STH*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I believe that your problem isn't understanding "for" loops in C but rather building the correct flow of your program (your "algorithm" if you will) before approaching the code.

Practice Pseudo-Code for this:

```
For Each Judge:
    Continue to ask for score until it is valid
```

Or you can break it down even more:

```
Beginning of loop:
Current Judge = 0
current Score = invalid
Do this while score is invalid
    ask score of current judge.

Increment Current Judge 
Unless no more judges, go to beginning of loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I agree with you that I have problem with the algorithm, I don't know how to approach to this question. thanks